# Pasar resultado de consulta SQL a un archivo TXT C#

Tags: c#

Actualmente estoy intentando escribir en un archivo txt el resultado de un query, el código que utilizo es este, pero la consulta trae dos columnas y solo logro escribir la primera columna.

```
 SqlCommand comando = new SqlCommand("Select x,m * from xxx", cn);
                        SqlDataReader leer;
                        leer = comando.ExecuteReader();
                        while (leer.Read() == true)
                        {
                            FileStream Query = new FileStream("C:/DatosQuery.txt", FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write);
                            StreamWriter Escriba = new StreamWriter(Query);
                            Escriba.Write(leer[0].ToString());
                            Escriba.Write(leer[1].ToString());
                            Escriba.WriteLine();
                            Escriba.Flush();
                            Escriba.Close();
                        }
```

Quedo atento a sugerencias, saludos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deberías cerrar el `StreamWriter` al terminar de escribir el archivo, es decir fuera del while y la creacion antes del mismo.

```
 FileStream Query = new FileStream("C:/DatosQuery.txt", FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write);
    StreamWriter Escriba = new StreamWriter(Query);
    SqlCommand comando = new SqlCommand("Select x,m * from xxx", cn);
    SqlDataReader leer;
    leer = comando.ExecuteReader();
    while (leer.Read())
    {              
      Escriba.Write(leer[0].ToString());
      Escriba.Write(leer[1].ToString());
      Escriba.WriteLine();
      Escriba.Flush();

    }    
Escriba.Close();
```

Comment: Al poner el Escriba.Close(); fuera me muestra un error, debe ser porque esta creado dentro del while, pero he sacado el FileStream y el StreamWriter y ha funcionado muchas gracias (Y)

Comment: Alli edite, la creacion tambien deberia estar fuera del mismo